# How do I determine where a word appears over multiple sentences?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following code that tells me how many times a word appears in a sentence.  Specifically, I have a 1D cell array of sentence strings and a 1D cell array of words that I want to use to search within each sentence.  This code is a 2D cell array where each row and column combination tells me how many times I see a particular word (column) appear in a sentence (row).  In other words:

```
Out = NaN(numel(sentences), numel(out_words));
   for i = 1:numel(out_words)    
   Out(:,i) = cellfun(@(x) numel(strfind(x, out_words{i})), sentences);
end

display(Out)
```

What I would like now is a 1D cell array `Out` where each element describes a word and within this element is a vector that tells you which sentences the word appears in.

For example, if the word is `trees` and `trees` is assigned an ID of 1, a potential vector within the cell element of `Out{1}` could be `[1,5,8]`, which means that the word `trees` appeared in sentences 1, 5, and 8.  Is there a way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: please provide some input data.

Comment: Why do you tag this with regex?

Comment: @thewaywewalk please see my post i updated it with an example, i hope u understand what i want to achieve.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad - Please consider accepting the other answers that were provided to you with the other questions you have asked.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers

Comment: So is it my understanding that you want a **logical** matrix where a row is a sentence and a column is a word and each row and column combination determines whether or not that word appeared in that sentence?  Your wording is rather obfuscated.  Also I don't quite understand that output.  Either show more examples, or modify it with another example that makes more sense.

Comment: @rayryeng i have a matrix where a row is sentence and column is a word and it shows logical output, what i want to do here is to make another matrix (**not logical**) whose output should be which word occurs in which number of sentence, by number i mean sentence number like s1, s2 ,s3,....,sn i don't want logical matrix i want matrix with integers.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking.  We get that it's a matrix... that's great.  What goes **inside** each element of this matrix?  What do these integers describe?

Comment: @rayryeng inside each element of matrix there should be sentence number in which specific word appears **for example** if trees appear in 4 different sentences its entry in matrix should show separately sentence number because i have labeled each sentence in text with (1,2,3,...n) i need to list this info in single element. like trees {1,4,7,9} these integers are u can say serial numbers of sentences

Comment: OK... so you don't want a 2D matrix.  You want a 1D **cell array** `Out` where each element describes a **word** and within this element is a vector that tells you which **sentences** the word appears in.  For example, if the word is `trees` and `trees` is assigned an ID of 1, a potential vector within the cell element of `Out{1}` could be `[1,5,8]`, which means that the word `trees` appeared in sentences 1, 5, and 8.  Am I understanding your problem correctly? #gomentalist

Comment: @rayryeng yes this is what i want to do,you are understanding my problem.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad - OK. We are getting somewhere :) Let me write an answer for you.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad - You're welcome.  I've taken the liberty in rewriting your question as it wasn't very clear.  I've also rewritten your title as what you are describing your title does not correspond to what you're actually asking.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad - I've also written an answer.  Review it, and if you are satisfied, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will reiterate what I asked in the comments so people on the StackOverflow community will know what the question is really asking:

---

The OP wants a 1D cell array `Out` where each element describes a word and within this element is a vector that tells you which sentences the word appears in.

For example, if the word is `trees` and `trees` is assigned an ID of 1, a potential vector within the cell element of `Out{1}` could be `[1,5,8]`, which means that the word trees appeared in sentences 1, 5, and 8.

---

One easy way to do this would be to loop over every word that you have and use [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) and see which elements in the output are **non-empty**.  For those locations that are non-empty, this would determine where the word has occurred in a particular sentence.  Let's do an example.  I'm going to choose six sentences to be the first six lyrics of [Bruce Cockburn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Cockburn)'s [Lovers in a Dangerous Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovers_in_a_Dangerous_Time).  I'll declare this to be in a cell array of strings called `sentences`.  To be sure we can find words correctly and not worry about case, we will convert all sentences to lower case with [`lower`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lower.html):

```
sentences = {'Don''t the hours grow shorter as the days go by',
'You never get to stop and open your eyes'
'One day you''re waiting for the sky to fall'
'The next you''re dazzled by the beauty of it all'
'When you''re lovers in a dangerous time'
'Lovers in a dangerous time'};

sentences = lower(sentences);
```

Next, I'm going to declare a `words` array that determines which words I want to find over all of the sentences:

```
words = {'you', 'one', 'dangerous', 'beauty', 'go', 'to'};
```

As such, the code you want is very simply:

```
Out = cell(numel(words), 1); %// Declare empty array of cells for each word
for idx = 1 : numel(words) %// For each word...
    K = strfind(sentences, words{idx}); %// See which sentences have these words
    ind = cellfun('isempty', K); %// Determine which locations are EMPTY
    Out{idx} = find(~ind); %// To find those locations that are non-empty, we need to find those entries that are 0, so search for the inverse
end
```

Let's go through the above code slowly.  We first declare a cell array of elements (1D) that is as long as the total number of words we have.  Next, for each word, we use `strfind` to determine whether we can find that particular word in all of the sentences.  `strfind` will return a cell array where each element in this array tells you the starting index (or indices if there is more than one occurrence) of where we have found this word.  If an element in this cell array is empty, this means that we did not find the word in the sentence.

Now, what we're going to do next is search within this cell array for any entries that are **empty**.  This can be done with `cellfun` and the output will be a `logical` vector where 1 means it's empty and 0 means it's non-empty.  We want to find those locations that are **non-empty**, and so we use `find` to search for locations that are **non-empty**.  These locations ultimately determine whether we have found that word in that sentence.

As such, if we run with the above example, this is what we get:

```
>> celldisp(Out)

Out{1} =

     2

Out{2} =

     3

Out{3} =

     5
     6

Out{4} =

     4

Out{5} =

     1 

Out{6} =

     2
     3
```

This means that for the first word, `you`, we have found this word in sentence #2, which is: `'you never get to stop and open your eyes'`.  Next, the second word is `one`, and we have found this in sentence #3, which reads: `'one day you're waiting for the sky to fall'`.  The next word is `dangerous`, and we have found this in sentences #5 and #6, which read: `'when you're lovers in a dangerous time'` and
 `'lovers in a dangerous time'`.  You can follow along with the rest of the cell array and you can verify that what each cell element gives you are the sentence IDs that tell you where each word appeared.

In your comments, you want to go further and make an associative array where you specify the **string** you want and the output will be the sentence IDs of the sentences that contain these words.  You can use a [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) class to do that for you.  Specifically:

```
out_dict = containers.Map(words, Out);
```

Now, you can do:

```
>> out_dict('dangerous')

ans =

     5
     6
```

If you want to input in multiple words, use the `values` method:

```
vals = values(out_dict, {'you', 'dangerous', 'go'})
celldisp(vals)

vals{1} =

     2

vals{2} =

     5
     6

vals{3} =

     1
```

If you want to display all of the words, just do:

```
vals = values(out_dict, words);    
celldisp(vals)

vals{1} =

     2

vals{2} =

     3

vals{3} =

     5
     6    

vals{4} =

     4

vals{5} =

     1

vals{6} =

     2
     3
```

---

BTW, I will reiterate this for you.  Please consider accepting the answers that were provided to you in your previous questions.  This signifies to the StackOverflow community that you no longer need help for your questions.  Since you like reading answers, you can read this to help you figure out how to accept answers: [How to update and accept answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers)

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer, one small thing i wanted to ask is what if i want to display name of the word in curly brackets for example: out{you}=2  instead of out{1}=2

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad - You will need to use a `containers.Map` container for that.   If you want, I can modify my answer.... but please do us a favour and accept your answers to the other questions.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad - Done.  Please remember what I said about accepting.

Comment: you have updated the code for single word i.e 'dangerous' what if i want to  pass a set of words to "out_dict(out_words)"  and out_words contain 5 words from different sentences i want to display all 5 words with 1 statment?

Comment: thanks a ton, actually i'm new to matlab environment that's why facing problems, i'll study documentation. thanks again

Comment: No problem. Sorry for my hostility but it's one of my pet peeves that someone asks several more questions after I have adequately solved the first one and these weren't asked in the original question. Don't take it personally. However don't let that stop that from asking more questions. Just make new ones! Good luck!